# google colab A100 is much slower than my local Nvidia RTX 3070, why?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

Learning pytorch here.  Got the following code from a book.  It runs fast on my Nvidia RTX3070 (every epoch took 3.6 seconds), but on Google colab, even if I choose the run time to be A100, each epoch took ~7 seconds.

Any idea why?
Thanks in advance!

```
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import transforms

torch.manual_seed(1)
batch_size = 128 
learning_rate = 1e-2 
num_epoches = 10 

train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
    root='./data', 
    train=True, 
    transform=transforms.ToTensor(), 
    download=True)  

test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
    root='./data',
    train=False, 
    transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True)


class Cnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, n_class):  # 28x28x1
        super(Cnn, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_dim, 6, 3, stride=1, padding=1),  # 28 x28
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),  # 14 x 14
            nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5, stride=1, padding=0),  # 10 * 10*16
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))  # 5x5x16

        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(400, n_class)) #120),  # 400 = 5 * 5 * 16
            #nn.Linear(120, 84),
            #nn.Linear(84, n_class))

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv(x)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), 400)  # 400 = 5 * 5 * 16,
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

model = Cnn(1, 10).to('cuda') 

print(model)

# loss和optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
import time
start = time.time()

for epoch in range(num_epoches):
    print('epoch {}'.format(epoch + 1))
    print('*' * 10)
    running_loss = 0.0
    running_acc = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        img, label = data
        img = Variable(img).to("cuda")
        label = Variable(label).to("cuda")
        out = model(img)
        loss = criterion(out, label)  # loss
        running_loss += loss.item() * label.size(0) 
        _, pred = torch.max(out, 1) 
        num_correct = (pred == label).sum() 
        # accuracy = (pred == label).float().mean()
        running_acc += num_correct.item() 
        optimizer.zero_grad() 
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print('Train Finish {} epoch, Loss: {:.6f}, Acc: {:.6f}'.format(
        epoch + 1, running_loss / (len(train_dataset)), running_acc / (len(
            train_dataset))))
    print(f"took {time.time() - start}")
    start = time.time()


torch.save(model.state_dict(), './cnn.pth')
```

Comment: I hope [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71003586/22324209) might add some value to this Question.

Comment: Thanks @GeneralTony for the link. It's very good to know when data for computation is small, CPU could be faster. Here, I am comparing two GPUs (my local RTX3070 vs Google Colab A100).  By the way, I changed the batch size from 128 to 2014, one epoch training time goes from ~7seconds to ~6seconds.  faster, but still not as fast as my local GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a bigger `batch_size` in `DataLoader` (e.g. 16 or 32). By default, `batch_size` is going to be 1, which quite slow.

Comment: This line is from the above code: `batch_size = 128`.  I haven't experimented with other batch sizes.    The GPU memory is enough. A100 has 80GB of VRAM.

Answer (score 0):

A 7 second epoch sounds really small. I feel like at that point you might be running into some sort of pcie bandwidth/latency limit. (Basically your `.to("cuda")` is probably really slow.)
You could try 2 benchmarks to narrow this down.

1. where you skip everything except the `.to("cuda")`
2. where you use the first batch and have the training part without `.to("cuda")`

1 -

```py
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        img, label = data
        img = Variable(img).to("cuda")
        label = Variable(label).to("cuda")
```

2 -

```py
    running_loss = 0.0
    running_acc = 0.0
    img, label = next(iter(train_loader))
    img = Variable(img).to("cuda")
    label = Variable(label).to("cuda")
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        out = model(img)
        loss = criterion(out, label)  # loss
        running_loss += loss.item() * label.size(0) 
        _, pred = torch.max(out, 1) 
        num_correct = (pred == label).sum() 
        # accuracy = (pred == label).float().mean()
        running_acc += num_correct.item() 
        optimizer.zero_grad() 
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

it could also be a data loading limit, but I don't think that should be the case because MNIST should fit in ram. You could also use cProfile (part of stdlib) or another profiler to check the timing in more detail.

Comment: thanks for the idea. the model `model = Cnn(1, 10).to('cuda')` is created for cuda, if I don't have the data (img and label) moved to cuda, it gave me an error when calling forward method of the model.  Could you clarify what you would like me to run?

Comment: The code snippets I gave were basically benchmarks. So the first one would run the dataloader without the model, and the second one would run the model train without the dataloader (by reusing the same first image from the dataloader 'img, label = next(iter(train_loader))`). By benchmarking it this way on colab and your pc, you can figure out what the bottleneck is.